# Где лучше хранить сессию на клиенте? В стородже или куках?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

Где лучше хранить sessionId? Я вызываю какой-то метод из апи, получаю sessionId и где мне его лучше сохранить, в куках или локалстородже? При заходе на сайт, я проверяю лежит ли он в куках/стородже. Если да, то сразу авторизовываю юзера, пропуская процесс авторизации.

Comment: А у вас, что, к сессионному id доступ из javascript имеется?

Comment: да. я олучаю его из бэкенда в каком-то закэшированном виде типа AAguNHuaJsbFoCvRrBcHаааааhVkfUPdHVqjo

Comment: и мне нужно его сохранить где-то

Comment: и при заходе на страницу, я вызываю новый метод на клиенте, оптравляя в запросе этот sessionId. если все ок, то пускаю юзера на страницу

Comment: Сессионый id должен передаваться сервером в браузер как кука. И браузер будет автоматически его отсылать на сервер при каждом запросе. При этом в куке должен быть выставлен флаг на запрет доступа к ней через javascript. Иначе любой js скрипт загруженный на страницу в браузере уведет у вас сессионный id.

Comment: @Visman оформите Ваш комментарий как ответ

Answer (score 0):

*Сессионый id* должен передаваться сервером в браузер как кука и браузер будет автоматически его отсылать на сервер при каждом запросе. При этом в куке должен быть выставлен флаг на запрет доступа к ней через javascript, иначе любой js скрипт загруженный на страницу в браузере уведет у вас *сессионный id*.

Ответ от [@Visman](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/186083/visman)